# Point light/spotlight attenuation in glsl 1.3+?

Tags: glsl

I've been working OpenGL's Superbible (5th Edition) point light examples.

I found them missing the constant, linear and quadratic attenuation values integrated into the old lighting model, so I went and wrote a point light shader with attenuation values based on this [ogre guide](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/-Point+Light+Attenuation).

The results have been completely bizarre. **What can be done to get a sensible light attenuation on the new glsl?  Is there a glsl table for attenuation constants?**

**Pics**

**Attenuation at distance 99** -sphere is black, light is blue-
  [image]

**Attenuation at distance 50** -sphere is black, light is blue-
[image]

**Attenuation at distance 16** -sphere is black, light is blue-
[image]

**Attenuation at distance 2** -sphere is black, light is blue-
[image]

**Sample vertex and fragment programs:**

Vertex program:

```
//point light per pixel vertex program 
#version 130

// Incoming per vertex... position and normal
in vec4 vVertex;
in vec3 vNormal;


uniform mat4   mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4   mvMatrix;
uniform mat3   normalMatrix;
uniform vec3   vLightPosition;

// Color to fragment program
smooth out vec3 vVaryingNormal;
smooth out vec3 vVaryingLightDir;

out float dist;
out float constantAttenuation;
out float linearAttenuation;
out float quadraticAttenuation; 

void main(void) 
    { 
    // Get surface normal in eye coordinates
    vVaryingNormal = normalMatrix * vNormal;

    // Get vertex position in eye coordinates
    vec4 vPosition4 = mvMatrix * vVertex;
    vec3 vPosition3 = vPosition4.xyz / vPosition4.w;

    //get distance to light source
     dist=length(vLightPosition-vPosition3);

     //write proper attenuation values

    if (dist<7.0){
      constantAttenuation=1.0;
      linearAttenuation=0.7;
      quadraticAttenuation=1.8; 
    }

    else if (dist<13.0){
      constantAttenuation=1.0;
      linearAttenuation=0.35;
      quadraticAttenuation=0.44; 
    }

    else if (dist<20.0){
      constantAttenuation=1.0;
      linearAttenuation=0.22;
      quadraticAttenuation=0.20; 
    }

    if (dist<32.0){
      constantAttenuation=1.0;
      linearAttenuation=0.14;
      quadraticAttenuation=0.07; 
    }
    if (dist<50.0){
      constantAttenuation=1.0;
      linearAttenuation=0.09;
      quadraticAttenuation=0.32; 
    }

    if (dist<65.0){
      constantAttenuation=1.0;
      linearAttenuation=0.07;
      quadraticAttenuation=0.017; 
    }

    if (dist<100.0){
      constantAttenuation=1.0;
      linearAttenuation=0.045;
      quadraticAttenuation=0.0075; 
    }



    // Get vector to light source
    vVaryingLightDir = normalize(vLightPosition - vPosition3);

    // Don't forget to transform the geometry!
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vVertex;
    }
```

Fragment program:

```
//point light per pixel fragment program 

#version 130

out vec4 vFragColor;

uniform vec4    ambientColor;
uniform vec4    diffuseColor;   
uniform vec4    specularColor;

smooth in vec3 vVaryingNormal;
smooth in vec3 vVaryingLightDir;

in float dist;
in float constantAttenuation;
in float linearAttenuation;
in float quadraticAttenuation; 

void main(void){ 

    float att;

    att = 1.0 / constantAttenuation + linearAttenuation*dist +quadraticAttenuation*dist*dist;

    // Dot product gives us diffuse intensity
    float diff = max(0.0, dot(normalize(vVaryingNormal), normalize(vVaryingLightDir)));

    // Multiply intensity by diffuse color, force alpha to 1.0
    vFragColor = att*(diff * diffuseColor +ambientColor); // attenuation affects the diffuse component

    // Specular Light
    vec3 vReflection = normalize(reflect(-normalize(vVaryingLightDir), normalize(vVaryingNormal)));

    float spec = max(0.0, dot(normalize(vVaryingNormal), vReflection));
    if(diff != 0) {
        float fSpec = pow(spec, 128.0);
        vFragColor.rgb += (att*vec3 (fSpec, fSpec, fSpec)); // attenuation affects the specular component
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any chance of images to help clarify "bizarre"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using just this attenuation values, the thing works acceptably:

```
      constantAttenuation=1.0;
      linearAttenuation=0.22;
      quadraticAttenuation=0.20;
```

There a couple of parenthesis missing on the attenuation division too.

Answer (score 1):

Your attenuation formula is completely incorrect:

```
att = 1.0 / constantAttenuation + linearAttenuation*dist +quadraticAttenuation*dist*dist;
```

Should be instead:

```
att = constantAttenuation / ((1+linearAttenuation*dist)*(1+quadraticAttenuation*dist*dist)).
```

That's why you are getting the sphere lighter when the distance increases. Try the proper formula and post the result.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that too. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the formula documented in the docs? I found "its intensity is attenuated by the reciprocal of the sum of the constant factor, the linear factor times the distance between the light and the vertex being lighted" at https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLight.xml which looks like the first formula.